# Scanning matrix keyboard using 74LS194

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, shift-register

I am trying to scan a matrix keyboard using a 74LS194.
The system works this way, there's an schematic below to support the explanation:

1. A parallel load is done to insert a '1' to be shifted (Load)
2. The system keeps on shifting the '1' until a key is pressed (!KeyDetected)
3. When a key is pressed (!KeyDetected), the bit is held to allow the system to read the Row and Column values.
4. Once the key is unpressed, the bit stops being held and is shifted again.

The user will never press more than one key at a time.

In simulator (proteus) works just fine.
In the circuit I have build around the design with LS TTL chips and 1k resistors is where I am getting the issue.

For some presses, the system works fine, but after some presses, when the key is unpressed the register outputs '0' in all the outputs.

I have been looking for days at all the pins at the oscilloscope and nothing is clear. For some reason, the bit is lost.

This is the oscilloscope reading of an output when the key is pressed. Apparently it is between the limits: [image: Osciloscope Reading].

**I am asking for the cause of this issue so I can fix it**

[image: Keyboard Scan System]

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, this is a Q&A site, what question you have? Please edit and add a question to your question.

Comment: `For some reason, the bit is lost.` ... think about what would cause the bit to shift past Q3

Comment: @jsotola, Q3 is connected to SR to keep it shifting, and it does for some presses...

Comment: that was a hint ... an extra clock pulse at the wrong time would make the bit disappear ... Q4 pulled low at the wrong time might do it, if you rely on recirculation

Comment: Are you just running the circuit in a simulator, or have you actually built it with LS TTL chip and 1k resistors?

Comment: @Justme, in simulator (proteus) works just fine. In the circuit I have build around the design with LS TTL chips and 1k resistors is where I am getting the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to 74LS194 chip datasheet, it has a recommended maximum output sourcing current of 0.4 milliamps which guarantees output voltage between 2.7 to 3.5 volts.

It means your 1k pull-down resistors load the output too much and an input may not determine it as logic 1 any more. Also the schematic has no bypass capacitors, so if your circuit has no bypass capacitors either, it may fail to work properly.

Comment: Thank you! Will removing the resistors fix the issue ?

Comment: @James221 \$I_{_\text{OH}}=400\:\mu\text{A}\$ is the standard sourcing current compliance for LS TTL parts. See [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTMfw.png). Also take careful note of \$V_{_\text{OH}}\$ and \$V_{_\text{IH}}\$. There's only about, worst case, \$400\:\text{mV}\$ separation when loaded down by \$400\:\mu\text{A}\$. Not a lot of noise margin, or margin generally. Just make sure you design around these details, carefully. That will include looking at the MCU datasheet, too.

Comment: You current circuit is working against TTL's strengths - change your logic so that a logic low is used to select the row with a pullup resistor on the columns - TTL has better sink than source specs. You'll see this in old skool designs. As well, you might want to add series diodes in the rows so multiple keypresses won't short circuit the LS194 outputs.

Comment: @Kartman Or just shift to devices that are open-collector, which is exactly what we used in *old skool* designs and which was also the very first parts TI made sure we had available back then, too. We pretty much never used TTL outputs for key-scanning. (And tri-state was like a luxury item that was years later in coming.)

Comment: @jonk - I can't recall too many TTL shift registers with open collector outputs. Usually a counter with a 7445 or later a LS156. Not forgetting 7406/07.

Comment: @Kartman Aren't any. We'd use the 74LS156, likely. It would be self-clocked and we'd use a 3-in AND gate to detect a STOP on a key and use that as a signal to capture the row and col and block (via an AND gate) the clock.

Comment: And throw in a 555 for good measure.

Comment: I have added an oscilloscope reading to the question, it looks like it is between the limits to what is considered to be a logical '1'

Comment: @James221 yes it proves that when button is pushed, it will connect 1k resistor between output and ground, so it loads the output too much and results in invalid voltages. So don't do that.

Comment: Yes, making the pull-downs even stronger will load the output by even more unreasonable amount and make the output signal much worse.

Comment: Hello, I have replaced the 1k pull-down to a 180 ohm pull-down, and it is even worse, the value on the output drops so much that at the very first press the bit is already lost. I am surely missing basic concepts from first course  analog electronics. Should I increase the value instead?

Comment: @Justme, I changed them from 1K ohm to 180 ohm, so I made the pull down weaker as a result, and it got worse.

Comment: No you did not make it weaker, you made it even stronger, about 5 times stronger.

Comment: 2.2k did the trick for me. Thank you!

Comment: Just be aware that the 2.2k load still exceeds the recommended chip limits.

Comment: @Justme, according to this site https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html it should be 2k, I thought 2.2k would be a good approximation.

Comment: Sure, a 2k might be a suitable value as a pull-down resistor value for a TTL chip input. But a TTL chip can't drive a 2k resistor as a load, with high enough voltage, for a TTL input to determine it as logic high.

Comment: @Justme, Okay, let's say I want to output 3V, knowing that the output current is 0.4mA, the resistor value should be, 7.5k, according to ohms law. Am I right?

Comment: I have tried multiple resistor values, after some presses, sooner or later it fails. Could it also be any problem at a logic level?